# How do I get a List<T> property in a class via reflection in C#?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class called `Animals` what contains two `List<T>`.
One is a list of bears, and one is a list of pinguins.

I can pretty trivially get the list of bears by just calling `Bears` on the `animals` variable - but how do I get it via reflection?

I have created a static helper class `ListHelper`, with a generic method that takes either `Bear` or `Pinguin` as the generic type, and animals as the argument which *should* return the list of bears if `Bear` is the generic type.

That doesn't happen. Instead it crashes with this message 
: `System.Reflection.TargetException: 'Object does not match target type`, and I cannot understand why, because the type is correct when I inspect it via the debugger.

Fully "working" example below.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System;

class ReflectionTrouble
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var animals = new Animals
        {
            Bears = new List<Bear> {new Bear {Name = "Bear1"}, new Bear {Name = "Bear 2"}},
            Pinguins = new List<Pinguin> {new Pinguin {Name = "Pingo1"}, new Pinguin {Name = "Pingo2"}}
        };

        var lists = ListHelper.GetList<Bear>(animals);
        foreach (var bear in lists)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(bear.Name);
        }
        //expected to have printed the names of the bears here...
    }
}

public static class ListHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetList<T>(Animals animals)
    {
        var lists = animals.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType);
        foreach (var propertyInfo in lists)
        {
            var t = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
            var typeParameters = t.GetGenericArguments();
            foreach (var typeParameter in typeParameters)
            {
                if (typeParameter == typeof(T))
                {
                    // This is where it crashes.
                    var list = (IEnumerable<T>) propertyInfo.GetValue(t);
                    return list;
                }
            }
        }

        return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    }
}


public class Animals
{
    public IList<Bear> Bears { get; set; }

    public IList<Pinguin> Pinguins { get; set; }
}

public class Bear
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Pinguin
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You are passing a `Type` instance to `GetType` while it expects an instance of the type.

Comment: `GetVaue` should be `var list = (IEnumerable<T>) propertyInfo.GetValue(animals);`  Although the reflection is very brittle.  You should be finding properties that are List<T> or where typeof(IEnumerable<T>).IsAssignableFrom() the property type.

Comment: I see I've gotten a downvote. Do you care to explain? Is there something wrong with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how to call [`propertyInfo.GetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue). The parameter you are passing to it should be the object whose property value you want to get. So in this case you are wanting the value of the property on animals so that line should be:

```
var list = (IEnumerable<T>) propertyInfo.GetValue(animals);
```

With this change your code is returning bears to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think a dictionary would be better solution here instead of reflection. Out of the box a dictionary should be able to handle all of your scenarios and offer much better performance. If you want to encapsulate it in a class then it might look like this.

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Animals
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, IList<IAnimal>> AnimalDictionary;
    public Animals(IList<IAnimal> animals)
    {
        this.AnimalDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, IList<IAnimal>>();
        this.Add(animals);
    }

    public Animals(IAnimal animal)
    {
        this.AnimalDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, IList<IAnimal>>();
        this.Add(animal);
    }

    public IList<IAnimal> Get<T>() where T : IAnimal
    {
        if (this.AnimalDictionary.ContainsKey(typeof(T)))
        {
            return this.AnimalDictionary[typeof(T)];
        }
        return (IList <IAnimal>)new List<T>();
    }

    public void Add(IList<IAnimal> animals)
    {
        foreach (IAnimal animal in animals)
        {
            this.Add(animal);
        }
    }

    public void Add(IAnimal animal)
    {
        this.AnimalDictionary.AddOrUpdate(animal.GetType(),
            new List<IAnimal>{animal}, 
            (type, list) =>
                {
                     list.Add(animal);
                     return list;
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However this does not really apply. The question I asked is a very trimmed version of the original problem, where that is not possible. I just did not want to post several hundreds lines of code :)